# How to make testcafe wait until a fixture is done executing before moving to the next fixture when using concurrency?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I want to run testcafe tests concurrently BUT only executing against 1 file at a time.
In other words, I want to wait for all the tests of a specific fixture to be done executing before the tests from the next fixture start executing.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the [TestCafe programming interface](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/).

Please see the following example:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;
let runner           = null;


createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe = tc;
        runner   = tc.createRunner()
            .browsers('chrome')
            .concurrency(3);
    })
    .then(() => {
        return runner.src('fixture1.js').run();
    })
    .then(() => {
        return runner.src('fixture2.js').run();
    })
    .then(() => {
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

However, please note that I run tests twice in sequence here. That means that your browsers will be opened twice too. You will also get two different reports.

Comment: Could you please describe what you mean by saying: "grouped multiple test files using meta tag"? If you run tests as @Alex Kamaev suggested:
`return runner.src('fixture1.js').run();`,
you can be sure that there is only one file that is executed at a time.

Comment: Where will I create this class with the code you posted?

Comment: Moreover, I don't want to hard code every test file name. I put all my tests under a folder and just specify that folder in the CLI which runs all the tests under it. I want testcafe to wait and move to next test file only once the previous test file has been compltely executed.